# Angular 6 Express application server rendering

Tags: angular, express, angular6, server-side-rendering

I have an application using Angular 6 and Express server. Now I want to add server rendering system (best and standard practices) but all of articles that I found are not compatible with Angular 6 or not using Express server in the normal way.

I just need the standard documentation for SEO friendly URLs (server rendering) for Angular 6 and Express server.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

Answer (score 0):

Recently (2 months ago), I also encountered into the same requirement. My client wants an web application with `angular 6 universal` with `express` server. he wants to use angular universal's SSR (Server Side Rendering) feature to achieve SEO with high speed web application.

After a lot of wondering on google I found a very well documented project and worked well with SEO purposes (I checked SEO compatibility which 90% got by Google Audit) on Github.
It also uses Express server to work with angular universal. You can checked it from the following link:
https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit

- To start it in development environment: use `npm start`
- To run it over express server (development): `node local.js`
- To build it in production environment with express server: use `npm run build:prod`